# Why doesn't this JS code run on older devices?

Tags: javascript, android, backwards-compatibility, openweathermap

I'm trying to build a simple MagicMirror in-browser weather app based on openweathermap API.

Knowing very little about coding, it proves a bit hard. I have this code, that someone corrected for me, but it won't run on older devices. [Here's the sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-forest-py0ud?file=/app.js:0-3746).

```
class Weather {
    constructor(data) {
      this.data = data;
      this.temp = Math.round(data.main.temp);
      this.feels_like = Math.round(data.main.feels_like);
      this.description = data.weather[0].description;
      this.city = data.name;
      this.country = data.sys.country;
      this.wind = Math.round(data.wind.speed);
      this.humidity = data.main.humidity;
    }
  
    geticonClass() {
      let prefix = this.data.weather[0].icon.endsWith("d")
        ? 'wi-owm-day-'
        : 'wi-owm-night-';
      return `${prefix}${this.data.weather[0].id}`;
    }
  }
  
  function fetchWeather() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      async (position) => {
        let url = new URL("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather");
        url.searchParams.set("lat", position.coords.latitude);
        url.searchParams.set("lon", position.coords.longitude);
        url.searchParams.set("lang", "pl");
        url.searchParams.set("appid", "fb7164d50e0faf1f058561b7903f03b9");
        url.searchParams.set("units", "metric");
  
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const weatherJSON = await response.json();
        updateDOM(new Weather(weatherJSON));
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error("Unable to get geolocation, Unsuported maybe?");
      }
    );
  }
  
  function updateDOM(weather) {
    const iconElement = document.querySelector(".today-weather-icon i");
    const tempElement = document.querySelector(".temperature-value p");
    const tempFeelElement = document.querySelector(".temperature-feel p");
    const descElement = document.querySelector(".temperature-description p");
    const locationElement = document.querySelector(".location p");
    const windElement = document.querySelector(".wind p");
    const humidElement = document.querySelector(".humid p");

    iconElement.classList.add(weather.geticonClass());
    tempElement.innerHTML = `${weather.temp}°<span>C</span>`;
    tempFeelElement.innerHTML = `Odczuwalna: ${weather.feels_like}°<span>C</span>`;
    descElement.innerHTML = weather.description;
    locationElement.innerHTML = `${weather.city}, ${weather.country}`;
    windElement.innerHTML = ` ${weather.wind} km/h`;
    humidElement.innerHTML = ` ${weather.humidity}`;
  }
  
  fetchWeather();
  setInterval(fetchWeather, 1800000);
  updateDOM();
  setInterval(updateDOM, 1820000);
```

[Here's a previous version of the code with navigator.geolocation that worked.](https://oldcont.netlify.app/)

Comment: Class in javascript was added in ES6/ECMAScript 2015, if your device browser doesn't support ES6, it won't recognize it. Could you give more information about the definition of "Older device"? also what type of browser are those older device using?

Comment: @Pascal I've tried multiple devices by now: Firefox 85.1.3 & Chrome 88.0.4324.152 on Android 8, Firefox 51.04.4 on Android 4.0.4, Firefox 51.04.4 on Android 4.2.2 and Firefox 85.1.3 on Android 5.1.1. It only works on Firefox 85.1.3 Android 10 and desktop with Win10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using modern ES6 syntax for example `class Weather` that's why. If you want to learn more about how you can convert it to pre ES6 syntax so it works on older devices too check this article [ES6 Class vs Object.prototyoe](https://medium.com/@ericschwartz7/oo-javascript-es6-class-vs-object-prototype-5debfbf8296e)
`

Comment: I have reverted to my previous iteration and everything works again. Thank you.